# Best way to get latest artifact version from Azure Artifacts in Azure Pipelines

Tags: angular, npm, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I'm uploading a Universal package to Azure Artifacts from an Azure Pipeline. I want to package the patched version number in the source of the artifact so I can display it in the view.

How should I do this?

This is an Angular project and the artifact is the result of `ng build --prod`.

This is the upload task:

```yaml
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  condition: eq(variables.isMaster, true)
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'Development/<name_redacted>'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '<name_redacted>'
    versionOption: 'patch
```

Comment: Can you add more details about your expected behavior? It looks like the configuration of your task can meet your needs.

Comment: I get the misunderstanding. What I'm missing is a way to also update the version in the source code (in the package.json for example). I need this to so I can show the deployed version in the webpage. This task only patches the version in the Artifact feed. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In Universal Packages, a particular package is identified by its name and version number. Whenever you publish a new version of the package, you can increase the version according to the updated content. Here is the document about [Package versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#package-versioning). You can also add description about the changes made in this version of the package. You can refer to the sample about use [Universal Package task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops#example).